# get database error code on SQLite exception in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, error-code

I use insertOrThrow in my android code to insert rows in to sqlite database. I use try catch to trap SQLiteException. I have set unique constraint in a column other than _id.
In case of errors i get exception message like the following and that is what i wanted.

> "column word is not unique (code 19)"

Now, if the error is about duplicate insertion then i get the above error. And i would get messages like that for different errors.

What i need is an error number like in mysql. I was searching for a property of the android DB object which would have an error code but could not. I think in this case i need to parse the error message to get the error code.

The reason to have an error code is to identify the errors. In this case i can find duplicates if the error code is 19. If the entry is a duplicate then i will display 'Data already exists' message else i will display a generic error info like 'Unable to save information'.

Is there any other way to find the error code other than parsing?
Will the error code be consistent?

Comment: Did you set the word column as Unique

Comment: Even if you could get the return code, does code 19 (constraint violation) uniquely (no pun intended) describe the cause? There could be other causes.

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15731975/4848308?

Comment: I have updated the question to make people understand it more clearly than before.

Comment: @JayapalChandran did you find a recommended way to get the sqlite error code?