# Autoincrement not working on ID

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having some trouble getting my autoincrement to work in SQL in my android app.

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "collections";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
        "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
```

Are there any major problems with the create statement that could cause this?

Comment: What is Logcat Showing?

Comment: Error inserting collection_id=1 reminder_id=0
                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columns reminder_id, collection_id are not unique (code 19)

Comment: If you're making changes to the database schema, you need to make sure to fully uninstall the application before you do the next build/install. Otherwise your database will in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731865/sqlite-error-column-id-is-not-unique-on-when-inserting-into-an-empty-table

Comment: Are you trying to insert a record with a repeated "_id" (id=1)?

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to insert a new record, but the id is not incrementing when I try to

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add `AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL` to the primary key, As primary key(column) is supposed to be auto-increment and it can't be null.
following is an example of a `SQL` query which you may edit to create your own table.

```
 public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT  EXISTS " + "Your_Table_Name" +
            " (" + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            "first_column_name" + " TEXT" + "," +
            "second_column_name" + " TEXT" + ")";
```

and `BaseColumns` is in interface provided by android in `package android.provider` which you may use to create a primary column with name `"_id"`

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a new value do not define id (it will be automatically generated) just use COLUMN_TITLE.

Even in scheme you can skip id definition, because sqlite use RAWID internally and latter aliases your ID to RAWID.